# kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters constant for iOS

Tags: location, ios

When leveraging the kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters constant, what location data is being used and where is that data stored when the OS pulls the data? The "last known location" used to be stored in cache.plist, but since iOS 4.2.8 that is no longer the case.

I am trying to gain a better understanding of how applications determine a device's location. The Core Location Framework allows calls for location-related data but hides the gritty details behind the API.

Comment: I can't think of a use case where you'd actually need this data - what's the reasoning behind needing to know it? Because of how iOS sandboxes applications its somewhat irrelevant where the underlying data is coming from

Comment: I'm curious about how accurate the returned location is, specifically, whether only GPS was used or a combination of Cell ID and WiFi was used to return the value. I am a detail-oriented person and enjoy learning about end-to-end processes. You are correct though-a returned value is really good enough and as long as the value is within certain parameters (as defined by the developer and in support of the application's functions) that should suffice.

Comment: Alas, I don't think there's any way to determine the source of the data (in a non-jailbroken device). If you're interested you can probably achieve this through a jailbreak, as you'll then be able to have access to the raw GPS sensor and actually figure out when it has been queried or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the apps that determine device location but the device. (hardware and software) The device in turn has the ability to inform the app about the device location via the Core Location API. Location is not tracked automatically, but you can ask the device to track it (again through the API).

The rationale behind constants like kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters is that an increasing localization accuracy costs increasing amounts of computation power. There is no point in investing in finding your position with an accuracy of 10 meters if all what you need is 100 meters.

Internally, there are two sources of data that are used to locate the device: 1. A GPS chip built into the device which is capable of receiving signals from GPS satellites surrounding the earth, which send timing information. As the signals arrive at different times because their distance to the device is differen and the speed of light is finite, the position can be calculated. 2. A database of visible SSIDs with their respective positions is used from which the proximity to their respective position is known.

That said, for you as an app developer it should be largely irrelevant how the respective data is stored internally in the device. All you need to know is the API.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters to the desiredAccuracy property of your CLLocationManager, what you are actually doing is suggesting the manager the level of accuracy you want on the location it reports to you. The CLLocationManager can be a gentleman and provide you with the desired accuracy, but sometimes, it is not possible for the locationManager to provide you with such level of accuracy. What you need to do is, in your delegate, when you are receiving the CLLocation objects, you look for the date the location was captured, and the horizontal/vertical accuracy properties. This will allow you to determine how accurate the data really is.

The CLLocationManager's location property will give you the last recorded location, even before reporting location changes to its delegate.